# Testing Laravel 4 Queue Faild jobs code

Tags: error-handling, laravel-4, queue

I am writing a listener in Laravel 4 for my Beanstalk Queue and all is well. However I also wanted to write some code to handle possible errors since I would like to know about them. I followed the documentation on the [Laravel doc site](http://laravel.com/docs/queues#failed-jobs) and wrote the something like shown below. 
I have two questions:

1. Is the constructor of my queue listener where I register my Queue::failing?
2. How do I test this code?

**UPDATE:**

So far I have gathered that the registering of Queue::failing() is basically the registering of an EventHandler. Laravel 4 does not really have a spot for that so this is what you make it. My current suggestio is not a brilliant place though.

For the testing of this I am still in the dark, even on something basic as to when the function/event is called/thrown. Could it be that these functions are called when an Exception is thrown during the handling of a message?

---

```
class QueueListener {
  function __construct () {
    Queue::failing(function($connection, $job, $data)
    {
       log::error('something went wrong!');
    });
  }

  public function fire($job, $data) {
     //process my data
  }
}
```

Comment: I would think it should be a function that belongs in your class such as 

public function fire($job, $data)

have

public function failing($connection, $job, $data)

Would make more sense to me being able to encapsulate the error within the queue service.

The docs don't mention where to place this so I assume you can add it to one of your start files. Since it's a static method method using closure, this seems to be global since the docs mentioned something about sending emails to the dev team or chat. I too would like this to be a little more clear rather than having to code dive the source

Comment: Thx for your reply. I'm afraid that browsing through the source is not my kind of thing. Even though, it comes across quite strange to put a method with a general name like Failing in the start files. I am aware that my interpretation of this is also not the most logical, yet I hope for someone who does to responde.